# Java EE SDK instead of Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I learned that Servlet reference implementation is included in the Java EE SDK. And Tomcat is a open source implementation of it.

Can I use Java EE SDK with Apache to render JSP pages instead of Tomcat? I think I can use Java EE SDK anywhere instead of JBoss or all Java EE compliant program. Is it right? 
Is it wrong when I use Java EE SDK?

**Update** [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html) it says that both Java EE and Glassfish implements Servlet API. I can download Java EE SDK, it's not just the specification. I wonder if Java EE is superclass of Glassfish.

Comment: Then, Can I use Java EE SDK with Apache to render jsp pages instead of Tomcat --->  you means Apache WebServer? Tomcat also from Apache

Comment: I mean Apache web-server. Apache webserver is not servlet container. It cannot itself render jsp&servlet pages.

Comment: So, question is whether use Apache webserver with Java EE SDK to render JSP.. :-) Good question, you need to understand what Java containers and what SDK means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java EE is a series of specifications. You can see the list of specifications in Java EE 6 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html).

All specifications, according to the [JCP](http://www.jcp.org), must have a reference implementation. The reference implementation for Java EE is [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) and this is what you probably call Java EE SDK.

In fact, other implementers can follow the specifications and provide their own server implementations. And that is why we have other servers out there like: [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/), [JoNas](http://wiki.jonas.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome), [Apache Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/), [IBM Websphere](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/) and [Oracle Weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index.html), among many others.

Now, coming back to the Apache issue. You could use Apache Web Server with [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html) enabled and forward requests to your Tomcat Server.

Now, Tomcat does not implement the whole set of specifications for Java EE. Tomcat is the reference implementation for JSPs and Servlets, as far as I know.

Comment: [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html)  says that both JavaEE & Glassfish implement servlet. And I can download JaveEE sdk, it's not just specifications. I wonder that JavaEE is superclass of Glassfish.

Comment: The Java EE pack which you download from Oracle contains Glassfish, Netbeans, the tutorial, documentation, examples, etc. The appserver part of Java EE SDK is **definitely** Glassfish. Although more targeted on JSF, you may find [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) a good read. Further, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165230/is-the-offical-sun-java-ee-tutorial-the-best-way-to-learn-how-to-make-java-web-ap/1876535#1876535).

Comment: @User As I already said above JEE implements the JSR 315 (Java Servlet 3.0), thus yes, all JEE 6 compatible servers offer servlets. I did not say JEE is just specifications, but I did mention that it has a reference implementation, and that is what you will get when you download the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Tomcat to render your jsp's. Look in the tomcat/webapps directory. You will see an examples directory with some jsp's.  You can create a simple jsp of your own in that directory and view it in a browser.  Tomcat normally runs on http://localhost:8080